# Magento Import error: image could not be downloaded from external resource

Tags: magento2, error, import

[image]

How can I solve this import error? I don't know what the error means. I tried many times but I don't know what's the error...

Comment: Check the folder permission of your images folder from where you are importing the images to products.

Answer (score 0):

while Uploading the `product`s you missed have `data miss match`/ `Missing required Data` in your `CSV` file.

1. Download full report.
2. Delete the row with error from your CSV file.
3. then upload you will have no errors.

Or

Try to upload `only 10 products` in your `CSV` file. Then you will understand the reason of you errors and were you are missing. make sure you provide all data which is required in product attributes.

In your Full report you can file the Reason for error.

Note: In Full report It will not Count your `Heading lines`. 
Hope this helps you. let me know if you have any issues further.